Name of "closure" of finite set of triples by adding all combination triples of distinct elements
I have a finite set of triples of elements $T$ with $|T|\geq 3$ and I wonder whether there is an established term for the following operator:
From the set $T$, choose $\binom{T}{3}$ elements, say $(r_1,s_1,t_1),(r_2,s_2,t_2),(r_3,s_3,t_3)$ and form the new triple $(r_i,s_j,t_k),i,j,k\in\lbrace 1,2,3\rbrace, i\neq j\neq k$. Necessarily, $(r_i,s_j,t_k)\not\in T $.
Is there a name for the new set containing $T$ and all possible $(r_i,s_j,t_k)$ generated from triples of triples in $T$? And also for the operator which does this?

Not following. Why must that new element fail to be in $T$?  Are you adding that as a condition for your operation or are you claiming that it somehow follows naturally?  And why does your new set contain $T$?  Regardless of all that, I wouldn't imagine that there is a name for the operation you are thinking of...it seems very context specific.

I think what you mean is this:  Given your set  $T$ of triples, let $T_1$ be the set of first elements, $T_2$, the set of second elements, and $T_3$ similarly.  Then you consider the Cartesian product $T_1\times T_2\times T_3$, right?

Yes, the condition that the new element is not in $T$ was context specific and is false in general. I change it. I want the new set to contain $T$ and the other triples, which the cartesian product, as you specify in the second comment, does.

Ok, so that's the "name", such as it is.  It's the Cartesian product of the three sets you can project onto naturally.
